# Where is the transistivity in this equivalence relation

Tags: relations

The following set has been given: $A = \{1,2,3\}$, and the following relation on $A$ has been given: $S = \{(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(2,2),(3,3)\}$. The answer says this is a valid equivalence relation. I can see how it is symmetric and reflexive, but I can't see how and why it is transistive. What am I not understanding?

Comment: It obviously has equivalence classes $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$. Two elements are related iff they are in the same equivalence class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that $\;(a,b)\in S,\,(b,c)\in S\implies (a,c)\in S\;$ for all the possible instances. For example

$$(1,2)\in S,\,(2,1)\in S\implies (1,1)\in S\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$

There is only one more instance to check...

Answer (score 0):

Can you find two pairs $\langle a,b\rangle,\langle b,c\rangle\in S$ such that $\langle a,c\rangle\notin S$?

If not then you can conclude that the relation is transitive.